# Dealing with big numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, biginteger

I'm trying to implement the Miller test in Haskell (Not Miller-Rabin.) I'm dealing with big numbers, and in particular I need to exponentiate big numbers and take the modulus of a large number mod another large number.

Are there any standard functions for doing this? The normal expt function ^ tells me I run out of memory before it computes a result. For example, I'd like to do:

(mod (8888^38071670985) 9746347772161)

I could implement my own algorithms, but it'd be nice if these already exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184296/why-can-haskell-handle-very-large-numbers-easily ..., your exponent is extremely large... however....

Comment: NVM about implementing my own. I looked at the Haskell implementations of these algorithms. They're exactly how I would have implemented them.

Comment: As I said... your exponent is ..., extremely large...

Comment: Maybe try to estimate how much memory you would need for storing your exponent. That is enormous number you want to store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is modular exponentiation (and much more) in the [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) package.

Since I wrote it, I'd be interested to hear if you find it useful and what could be improved.

If you try to compute

```
(mod (8888^38071670985) 9746347772161)
```

as it stands, the intermediate result `8888^38071670985` would occupy roughly 5*10<sup>11</sup> bits, about 60GB. Even if you have so much RAM, that is close to (maybe slightly above) the limits of GMP (the size field in the GMP integers is four bytes).

So you also have to reduce the intermediate results during the calculation. Not only does that let the computation fit into memory without problems, but it's also faster since the involved numbers remain fairly small.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. I should have done this from the beginning. I don't know why I didn't. I've been staring at the algorithm for a while now anyways. For whatever reason, I kept trying to do the expt and the mod separately and didn't put it together to use properties of congruences to reduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation to your number before taking modulo is

```
  10^log(8888^38071670985)
= 10^(38071670985 * log(8888))
= 10^(1.5 * 10^11)
```

In other words it has around 1.5 * 10^11 digits. It would need around

```
1.5 * 10^11 / log(2) / 8 / (2^30) = 58GB
```

of memory just to represent.

So starting with this may not be the best idea. Does the library *have* to support calculation with this large numbers?

Comment: Modular exponentiation does not require keeping the "number before taking modulo"